# Is there a way to ignore temporary folders in RTC client?

Tags: version-control, ignore, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I have temporary files created in separate folders inside my source tree which I would like to ignore. Something like:

```
project/
 |--component/
     |--.jazzignore
     |--file.src
     |--file-9df29e29373e66caef72/
         |--file.src.tmp
```

I already ignore `file.src.tmp` by extension using `.jazzignore`, but I would also like to ignore the `file-9df29e29373e66caef72/`. The folder looks empty in the "Unresolved" category for the component, but since its name changes over time, I cannot ignore it by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> since its name changes over time, I cannot ignore it by name.

Still, if you know its naming convention, you might consider an ignore pattern:

```
core.ignore= \
  file-*
```

Note it is non-recursive, you that would ignore any file, folder or symlink named `file-...` anywhere under `component`.
Here, that would ignore only `file-...` directly under `component`.

Comment: I was hoping to ignore these folders by the fact that they contain no useful files, but apparently finding a pattern for the naming convention is the only option. Thanks.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, at least that is my experience of that kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse workspaces often include files or folders, such as compiler output, log files, and so on, that you do not want to place under source control.
You can specify resources or classes of resources to be ignored by Rational Team Concert™ source control. Ignored resources are never checked in.

A .jazzignore file is used to prevent items from being checked into change sets.
A .jazzignore file consists of a series of patterns. Any file, folder, or symbolic link whose name matches a pattern cannot be committed to a change set.

There are two types of patterns in a .jazzignore file:

core.ignore patterns, that are effective in the same directory as the ignore file; and
core.ignore.recursive patterns that affect items in all of the directories below the .jazzignore file.